# Keep dictionary state with in the methods in a same class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, caching

I have below test class, Where I am defining _cacheExecutor dictionary at class level, and the purpose is mainly to cache the results with type T and test data as keys.

```
public class CodesAndGuidelinesTest : SchemaCache, IClassFixture<PostgreSqlResource>
{       
    private readonly Dictionary<(Type, object), Task<IRequestExecutor>> _cacheExecutor = new();
    public CodesAndGuidelinesTest(PostgreSqlResource resource) :base(resource) { }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Create_Name_Contains_Expression()
    {
        IRequestExecutor requestExecutor = await CreateSchemaAsync(CodesAndGuidelinesMockFixture.codeStandardGuidelines, _cacheExecutor);
        .......
        .......  
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Create_Name_NotContains_Expression()
    {
        IRequestExecutor requestExecutor = await CreateSchemaAsync(CodesAndGuidelinesMockFixture.codeStandardGuidelines, _cacheExecutor);
        .......
        .......  
    }
}
```

Below is the SchemaCache class

```
public class SchemaCache : QueryTestBase
{
    public SchemaCache(PostgreSqlResource resouce) : base(resouce) { }
    public Task<IRequestExecutor> CreateSchemaAsync<T>(T[] entities,
                                                       Dictionary<(Type, object), Task<IRequestExecutor>> cacheExecutor) where T : class
    {
        (Type, T[] entites) key = (typeof(T), entities);
        if (cacheExecutor.TryGetValue(key, out var result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else // else block will always be executed when I run the test methods all at once
        {
            cacheExecutor[key] = CreateDb(entities);
        }
        return cacheExecutor[key];
    }
}
```

In the above class, I store the test data and type combined as keys in the dictionary and the results `Task<IRequestExecutor>` as values.

When executing the test methods all at once, For the first test method, it goes to the `createDb`, and the keys and values are stored in `_cacheExecutor`, and for the following test method `_cacheExecutor` has null values and thus it's going into the else block. The else block will always be executed because of the dictionary at class-level declaration, and for the new method, the `_cacheExecutor` will be null.

Could anyone please let me know any better solution or suggestion?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you clarify, are you saying each test is unaware of the cache (i.e. each test is fully unique) and you want them to share cache, or are you saying the tests are overlapping cache data and you don't want that.

Comment: It looks like each test is unaware of the cache, But I do want those methods should share the cache

Comment: That's not how it should work. Each test is in isolation. If they're not, then that's a problem. If you need a starting point for each test, then you'll need to perform a setup per test to "seed" the data.

Comment: In theory, you can force your test runner to run each test one after the other, but I'd recommend not trying to muck with things like that.

Comment: I am looking kind of the same "seed data." If you see in the above question, I am passing data "CodesAndGuidelinesMockFixture.codeStandardGuidelines" and dictionary to avoid calling method `CreateDb.`

Comment: But in `schema cache,` I am calling another method, "CreateDb(entities)," where I am adding the data to DB and returning `IRequestExecutor` and storing it in a dictionary at the end. So for the following method, I am calling the same